# Class extensions and frameworks

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

I have develop my own framework that contains useful classes/methods that I often use in my apps. Recently, I've added a class extension for NSString "NSString+Extensions.h/m" to add my own methods. Example :

- NSString+Extensions.h

> ```
> @interface NSString (Extensions)
> - (NSString *)removeDiacritics; 
> @end
> ```

- NSString+Extensions.m

> ```
> #import "NSString+Extensions.h"
>
> @implementation NSString (Extensions)
>
> - (NSString *)removeDiacritics
> { 
>     return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
> }
>
> @end
> ```

I successfully compile my framework. But when I try to use one of the functions of this class extension in any application :

- AppDelegate.m

> ```
> // CUtils is the name of the framework. CUtils.h contains #import of all header files
> // contained in my framework
> #import <CUtils/CUtils.h>
>
>
>   @implementation AppDelegate
>
>     ...
>
>     - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
>     {
>         /*
>          Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previouslyin the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
>          */
>
>         NSString *toto = @"Je suis une chaîne avec des caractères spéciaux";
>         NSLog(@"%@", toto);
>         NSLog(@"%@", [toto removeDiacritics]);
>     }
> ```
>
> ...

I get the following error :

2012-01-31 17:01:09.921 TestCUtils[4782:207] Je suis une chaîne avec des caractères spéciaux
2012-01-31 17:01:09.924 TestCUtils[4782:207] **-[__NSCFConstantString removeDiacritics]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x340c**

But if I add my class extension directly in the application (outside of my framework), it works fine...

Any hint?

** EDIT **

As some of you have asked, I've added -all_load and -ObjC options in 'Other Linker Flags', but the issue remains.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this [technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html) that explains the -ObjC and -all_load options that @Ell Neal mentions.

**Note** The linker options need to be set on the project that is linking the framework (i.e. the client of the framework) **not** the framework itself. From your screenshot it looks like you are setting the option on your framework project because I can see the source file `NString+Extensions.m` on the left.

Comment: Awesome! it works. I've added only the -ObjC linker flag in my application target and this is working. I have a question though. In my framework, I've created a class to manage SQLite database, so I need ti link the libsqlite3.dylib. When I add my framework in my application with this new linker flag, I have compilation errors due to the fact I do not link the libsqlite3.dylib, even if I already linked it inside my framework (don't know if I'm clear enough). Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: This probably qualifies as a separate question. In general, you will need to explicitly link the dependent libraries in your application. It would be nice if linking a custom framework would also pull in the dependent libraries but I don't think there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `-ObjC` to *Other Linker Flags* in your build settings. If this doesn't work, try adding `-all_load`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. i've already done that : same issue.

Comment: I think this answer is correct, are you sure that you add both of these flags to your active target? Sometimes I added them to my project and forgot to inherit them in the target, and this was why I didn't see my categories.

Comment: @lawicko : yes, I've added those options to my target, please have a look on my edited post.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the static library target. These flags should be on you application target that is importing the library.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to `#import "NSString+Extensions.h"` in your AppDelegate.m

Comment: Not doing this would only cause a build warning, not a crash.

Comment: In AppDelegate.m, I've added #import <CUtils/CUtils.h>. CUtils is my framework name, CUtils.h contains #import of all header files contained in my framework (NSString+Extensions.h included)

Comment: I believe you will need all the h files